# MySQL NOT IN statement with other parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two pages. On the first page, a random row from my database is selected and displayed. A form is then submitted. On the second page, I want a random row from the database to be selected, but I need the one that was already chosen at random *to be excluded* from that query.

I've seen `NOT IN` as a way to do this but it doesn't seem to work in conjunction with `RAND()` or `LIMIT` though I may just have the order of the operators wrong. Here's the code I've got so far that's not working:

```
$sql_new = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 NOT IN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id')";
$result_new = $mysqli->query($sql_new);
```

This doesn't return any information. Any help on syntax would be great.

Comment: Please check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html especially how and where to put `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql_new = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id != '$id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";
$result_new = $mysqli->query($sql_new);
```

Comment: +1. Wondered why use an exclusion here, especially on a complete set of columns (*)... I always thought IN and NOT IN should be applied to columns specifically. Anyway :)

Comment: It is not a good practice to enclose `int` value with quotes - because in that case DB will perform string to int cast before comparison.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo You are right - but what makes you sure that `id` is an `int` actually? OP didn't mention that...

Comment: Let them, who uses something rather than `int` for `id` field, being cursed :p Ok, you're correct, topic started not specified that. Just feeling uncomfortable when seeing int-to-string comparison :p

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL Docs say

> To comply with the SQL standard, IN returns NULL not only if the
>   expression on the left hand side is NULL, but also if no match is
>   found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is NULL.

You need to provide a column name before the **NOT IN** keyword. Something like this

```
SELECT val1 FROM tbl1 WHERE val1 NOT IN (1,2,'a');
```